# Migrate from tfs repo to gitlab community edition

Tags: git, tfs, gitlab

It's possible to migrate from TFS (Team Foundation Server) 2017 git repository to gitlab with saving the git history ?

Thanks

Comment: You will find a lot of documentation but it looks like: `git clone --mirror` then `git remote set origin <new_url>` and finish with `git push origin --all`

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22265837/transfer-git-repositories-from-gitlab-to-github-can-we-how-to-and-pitfalls-i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the Git Repo history hence no boards, user stories, tasks, pipelines in TFS. Then you can do it **directly with Git command line**. Simply change the remote url from Azure DevOps to GitLab and push your local repo to remote same as the way *Philippe* mentioned in the comment.

When you import a Git repository from  Azure DevOps(or any Git server) to  GitLab , all the branches and folders will be imported with all the history (commits).

If you want to do this through Visual Studio, you could refer  this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60023755/5391065).