# Azure DevOps Repos TFVC Transfer from one organization to another with Full history

Tags: azure, migration, devops

I need help regarding Azure DevOps TFVC repos transfer from one organization to another with full history.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I move an Azure DevOps project to a different organization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53366512/how-do-i-move-an-azure-devops-project-to-a-different-organization)

Comment: No it shows only with Git Repos. My Repos in Azure DevOps TFVC want to transfer to another organization in Azure DevOps with Full history.