# Migration of projects in azure Devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

Is this possible to migrate projects from one organization to another in Azure DevOps?

I am facing challenges to manage multiple organizations so instead of it I want to migrate all of the projects to a single organization.

Comment: This tool could help you accomplish your migration. https://github.com/nkdAgility/azure-devops-migration-tools . Attaching also another discussion on this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53366512/how-do-i-move-an-azure-devops-project-to-a-different-organization

Comment: will it migrate pipelines as well?

Comment: In the documentation section `What can you do with this tool` it is stated that you can Migrate Work Items, TestPlans & Suits, Teams, Shared Queries, Pipelines, & Processes from one Organisation to another

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the requirement of migrating one organization project to another organization ***`will not be achieved directly`*** through DevOps. Instead there are few operations we can perform in Azure DevOps where we can implement to achieve the task up to some point.

There are different migration tools like:

1. Migration Tools for Azure DevOps : https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nkdagility.vsts-sync-migration
2. OpsHub Azure DevOps Migrator (Formerly known as OpsHub Visual Studio Migration Utility) : https://www.opshub.com/products/opshub-azure-devops-migrator/

Instead, we can migrate the REPO by `Built-in clone functions` and `export data through excel sheet`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/devops/report/admin/create-status-and-trend-excel-reports?view=tfs-2017&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops-2020

[image]